# Springboot Security Filter confusion

Tags: spring-boot, oauth

I have been following tutorials on how to set up security with Springboot. Can someone explain to me what this line does:

```
.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
            )
```

Does it just make sure the Bearer token is in JWT format? Or does it actually contact Google (I use it for log in) to verify the JWT token

It is located in:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

```
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                .requestMatchers("/api/secure/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll())
        .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
        )
        .sessionManagement((session) ->
                session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        )
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()
        );

    http.csrf(csrf->csrf.disable());
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All that you need to know you can find in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) about configuration and working way of OAuth 2.0 Resource Server Part

As a short explanation:

There you tell to `spring-security` that your resource server part support just `jwt` tokens type using the oauth2ResourceServer() [DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl). Also `Customizer.withDefaults()` mean that all configuration that can have `jwt` like `decoder` and so one will be as default one.

More details and deep understanding about how it work and why it work in this way you will find in above references.